# JavaFX FXML include fxml causes NullPointerException

Tags: javafx, include, fxml

I want to extract a button to a new fxml file and change the main label with it. Without extraction it works perfectly.

main.fxml:

```
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="org.example.MainController">
   <Label fx:id="label" text="default"/>
   <Button onAction="#changeLabel" text="sayHello" />
</VBox>
```

MainController:

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void changeLabel() {
        label.setText("Changed");
    }
}
```

With extraction I get NullPointerException in MainController.changeLabel()

 main.fxml with include:

```
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="org.example.MainController">
   <Label fx:id="label" text="default"/>
   <fx:include source="button.fxml"/>
</VBox>
```

button.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="org.example.MainController">
    <Button onAction="#changeLabel" text="sayHello" />
</AnchorPane>
```

What can cause this NPE?

Comment: Since we don't know what line is throwing the NPE or any of the code that goes with it, this isn't going to be answerable. Please include a [mcve] for debugging help.

Comment: I get NullPointerException at MainController.changeLabel(MainController.java:12) as I mentioned, or isn't this enough?

Comment: No, because it could be your `MainController` that is null or something inside the `changeLabel()` method. Without seeing your code, we would only be guessing.

Comment: There is no element in `button.fxml` with `fx:id="label"`, so clearly `label` will be null in the controller for that FMXL file.

Comment: Is there any way to reach the label in main.fxml via button.fxml?

Comment: You can inject he controller for the included FXML (the "nested controller", in the language of the [standard documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers)) into the controller for the "including" FXML, establishing communication between them. Another (perhaps better) way is to use a MVC architecture and just update a shared, observed model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should (almost?) always use a different class for controllers for different FXML files. (The only exception I can think of is if you want to define different FXML files to represent different layouts for the same controls.)

One approach is to inject the controller for the included FXML (the "Nested Controller") into the main controller. (See [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers).)

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private ButtonController buttonController ;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {    
        buttonController.setOnButtonPressed(this::changeLabel);
    }

    private void changeLabel() {
        label.setText("Changed");
    }
}
```

```
public class ButtonController {

    private Runnable onButtonPressed ;

    public void setOnButtonPressed(Runnable onButtonPressed) {
        this.onButtonPressed = onButtonPressed ;
    }

    public Runnable getOnButtonPressed() {
        return onButtonPressed ;
    }

    @FXML
    private void changeLabel() {
        if (onButtonPressed != null) {
            onButtonPressed.run();
        }
    }
}
```

And then the FXML files look like

```xml
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="org.example.MainController">
   <Label fx:id="label" text="default"/>
   <fx:include fx:id="button" source="button.fxml"/>
</VBox>
```

and

```xml
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="org.example.ButtonController">
   <Label fx:id="label" text="default"/>
   <fx:include source="button.fxml"/>
</VBox>
```

---

Generally speaking, it's a bad idea for controllers to have references to each other, as it breaks encapsulation and adds unnecessary dependencies. A better approach is to use a MVC design.

```
public class Model {

    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty() ;

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text ;
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private Label label;

    private final Model model ;

    public MainController(Model model) {
        this.model = model ;
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {    
        label.textProperty().bind(model.textProperty());
    }

}
```

and

```
public class ButtonController {

    private final Model model ;


    public ButtonController(Model model) {
        this.model = model ;
    }

    @FXML
    private void changeLabel() {
        model.setText("Changed");
    }
}
```

The FXML files are as above, and you need to specify a controller factory when you load the FXML (so that the controllers are instantiated by passing the model instance to the constructors):

```
final Model model = new Model();

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/path/to/main.fxml");
loader.setControllerFactory(type -> {
    if (type.equals(MainController.class))   return new MainController(model);
    if (type.equals(ButtonController.class)) return new ButtonController(model);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected controller type: "+type);
});
Parent root = loader.load();
// ...
```